# mysql (phpmyadmin) rows inserted from a vb application don't get updated

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, phpmyadmin

I'm facing a mysql - phpmyadmin problem, i have made a vb application to insert rows in a loop to mysql database, no errors occur when inserting and it does insert them, but when i run a query in phpmyadmin in the table where i inserted rows, to select specific rows depending on a varchar, it doesn't fetch them and always returns 0 rows affected, it doesn't even update them, when i tried to add a row manually using phpmyadmin, and tested these queries on it, it worked.
some help please? what code(s) do i need to post here?

to sum up everything;
1- I created a vb application which uploads specific data to mysql
2- The query succeed and inserted the data in the table as desired
3- when i go to phpmyadmin to update ANY of these rows or SELECT some of them, it always returns 0 rows affected, or zero records were found, the SELECT query was:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='john'
```

- that row exists, but the query turns zero records
- when i add a row manually using phpmyadmin it works perfectly, updates it, finds it using SELECT, but with rows which were inserted using the vb application, none works.

vb code:

```
qstr = "INSERT INTO users (name, age, manager) VALUES (@name, @age, @address)" com = New MySqlCommand(qstr, con)
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",name)
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age",age)
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manager", ismanager) com.ExecuteNonQuery()`
```

Comment: you need to show the code you have written so far.

Comment: qstr = "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `age`, `manager`) VALUES (@name, @age, @address)"
                com = New MySqlCommand(qstr, con)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",name)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age",age)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manager", ismanager)
                com.ExecuteNonQuery()
                
name is a varchar sized 22
age is an int sized 10
manager is int sized 2

Comment: add your code to the question not to comments - it's very difficult to read. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: sorry, will do it immediately, and thank you for giving attention to my issue

Comment: ok so you are looking for a row where name = john. Can you prove the VB is definitely passing "john" to the name parameter (and with no leading/trailing spaces or other characters)? Also if you do `select * from users` (without the where clause) in phpmyadmin, does it return all the rows including the ones your VB application has inserted?

Comment: ah for length, which i'm suspicious of, i added a row manually "Mark" and got it's length using a query, and it was 4, but when i used the same query on the rows which were added by vb application, they were the characters count + 1, is this a vb issue? as for the second question, yes it does, it returns all the rows my vb app inserted

Comment: it's not specifically something that VB does, no. Are the fields coming from user input, or somewhere else? Either way you should check them before entering into the database to see that they are in the format you require, including having no whitespace at either end of the string.

Comment: solved, really thanks, it was indeed a visual basic issue, i had to substring lines in a text file, i thought that the index of the first character in each line is 0, but it was 1, and nope it's not user input, it's fetching some strings from a text file, thanks again. but i got a question, is in vb the first character of a line, its index is 1 not 0?

Comment: in the substring function, it uses zero-indexing (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx). So either whatever is reading the lines is doing something unusual, or maybe the first character of each line is a space

Comment: pretty sure it's not, but thanks anyway, is there away i could reward you? like adding a reputation?

Comment: If you're solved this, the community here does **not** want titles with `SOLVED` all over the place. We want you to **add an answer** and then mark then answer accepted.

Comment: @Just_Cause I'll add my suggestions from the comments as an answer and you can mark it as the answer, that's the best way. Then the answer is there for others facing the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Following on from discussion in comments above). If you're not getting the output you expect, you should first check your input. So if your query on "name = john" isn't returning anything, then check that "john" is actually in the database field correctly.

For instance, a common problem is whitespace at the beginning and end of fields. Check there's no whitespace in the string you're submitting to the database. If there is you can use string functions such as trim or substring to try and remove it.